# Is there a way to add a JavaScript bookmarklet so that when the web page shows some content, then play an alert sound and fire a notification?

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, bookmarklet

I think this can be done using HTML5 audio, with a link to an external audio file, but is there a way to not use any file and play some sound? (similar to the system alert sound or the audio bell as in `\a` on the command line)

I think the notification part should be simple to do. We can just fire up a notification as usual.

The detail is: for any website, of which you are not the owner, let's say the web page keeps on showing some data, a number from 0 to 6000. Now if you use want to add a bookmarklet so that whenever the number (being shown as `value: 5200`) is greater than 5000, then play an audible sound and fire off a notification, without using an external audio file, is that possible and how can it be done?

Answer (score 2):

There is no access to trigger system sounds from a web page.

But you can embed a small sample-file via the Data-URI protocol and set that as `src` for the audio element.

Simply encode the audio file itself as Base-64 and prepend a Data-URI header using the correct mime-type (or have it [done for you](http://www.epistemex.com/datauri/)).

**Example:**

```js
document.querySelector("audio").src = "data:audio/mpeg;base64,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";
```

```html
<audio controls autoplay></audio>
```